# Using Shared Prefrences in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android development and I am stuck on one problem, where I need to use shared preferences.

Main.java

```
WebServiceInterface webinterface;

ProgressDialog progdial;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler     =   new Handler();
    webinterface=   new WebServiceInterface(wslogin);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getuser = username.getText().toString();
            getpass = password.getText().toString();


        /*****
             * setting values in HASHMAP 
             * 
             * 
             */

            HashMap<String, Object> map =  new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("username", getuser);
            map.put("password", getpass);

            /*****
             * calling sendRequest() method in WebInterface class
             * 
             */
            webinterface.sendRequest(map);

    //for getting values from preferences
       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
         String getResponse = prefs.getString("responsevalue", "");
       //but its getting error as showing NULLPOINTERException. 
        System.out.Println("response is -----  " + getResponse);
//here i am getting null value for gerResponse. .....               
        }
    });
}
```

WebInterface.java (only class not activity)

```
public class WebServiceInterface{


public WebServiceInterface(String getstring)
{       
    getWebServiceType = getstring;      
}

public void sendRequest(Map<String, Object> map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Collection<Object> strings = map.values();
    Iterator iterator = strings.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        getuser = (String) iterator.next();
        ast.add(getuser);
    }

    String password = ast.get(0).toString();
    String username = ast.get(1).toString();

  //calling webservice client to request webserivce code
    RestClient client = new RestClient(
            "http://**********************8");
    client.AddParam("username", username);
    client.AddParam("password", password);

    try {
        client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      //getting response back from Restclient and saving in response string. 
    String response = client.getResponse();

   //for setting values in preferences
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("responsevalue", response);
   editor.commit();


}
```

Here's the problem that I am facing:
 I want to access the response in the onCreate block at the Main.java file. **At Main.java file in the button click method I need to show toast with the following response getting in Webinterface class.**

Can anyone please help me with this. As I am new to android development, any small help will be appreciated.

The following is the stacktrace..

```
10-29 13:07:44.042: I/global(379): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
10-29 13:07:44.062: D/AndroidRuntime(379): Shutting down VM
10-29 13:07:44.062: W/dalvikvm(379): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.leads.doctorgokhale.Interface.WebServiceInterface.call(WebServiceInterface.java:44)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.leads.doctorgokhale.Interface.WebServiceInterface.sendRequest(WebServiceInterface.java:39)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.leads.doctorgokhalenative.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:154)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-29 13:07:44.072: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 13:07:44.143: D/dalvikvm(379): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3188 objects / 215024 bytes in 64ms
```

Comment: where you got error (which line)?

Comment: where's your preference activity?

Comment: You should post your stack trace.

Comment: I updated the code. Once chek the following & please do the needful...

Comment: @JasonRobinson error getting in stack trace is NullPOinter Exception in Main.java file where i am trying to get shared prefrence values.

Comment: Can you check to see if `client.getResponse()` returns a `null` value?

Comment: no it's returning response value. so, i am able to get those values in Webinterface clas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Relace

```
editor.putFloat("responsevalue", response); to below code

editor.putString("responsevalue", response);
```

You are trying to add string to float and get back it string, so you get error.

**Edit :**

You are accessing submit (button onClick event) before initialize it , so please initialize it . Do same for username,password edit Text .

```
submit   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But my problem is getting null values in Main.java file.. As i updated the code once check it...

Answer (score 0):

Write below code line

```
editor.putString("responsevalue", response);
```

instead of

```
editor.putFloat("responsevalue", response);
```

Add Below code into your `onCreate()` method after `setcontentview();`.

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But my problem is getting null values in Main.java file.. As i updated the code once check it...

Answer (score 0):

use

> putString

instead of

> putFloat

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `prefName` is `null`. `getResponse` shouldn't be null since you are giving it a fallback of an empty string.

Comment: but as per my code, in Main.java file i am getting null reponse.How can that be possible as i setting values in WebInterface Class i need to access those values in Main.java file but getting null values. So, any help regarding this.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I've requested to see the stack trace.

Comment: @user1578518 Thanks for posting the stack trace. It indicates the crash is happening in the `call()` method, yet I don't see that you have that posted. If you can include that, I can tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if (response == null)
        editor.putString("responsevalue", "response is null");
    else
        editor.putString("responsevalue", response);
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

does prefName in

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

hold any reasonable value, or is it an uninitialized variable?

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context Object to your WebInterface from Main.java (Activity)

```
webinterface=   new WebServiceInterface(this,wslogin);
```

change the constructor to :

```
Context mContext;
public WebServiceInterface(Context context, String getstring)
{       
    mContext =context;
    getWebServiceType = getstring;      
}
```

Display the toast from your WebServiceInterface :

```
 String response = client.getResponse();
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, response, duration);
 toast.show();
```